# How to match a line with exactly n occurrences with regex?

Tags: regex, line, python-re, exact-match

I am trying to match the lines containing exactly two semicolons (using Pythons re library):

```
 text;text;text;
 text;text;
 text;text;text;text;
 text;text;
```

However, I can't figure out how to not also include every line with more than 2 semicolons.
So far I came up with this:

```
(?=.*[;]){2}$
```

This is how I understand the code:

(?=.*[;]) This part looks ahead and matches any and all characters as long as the are followed by one semicolon. With {2} this part is then matched exactly 2 times. After the second Semicolon the line ends ($).

Any pointers?

Comment: You need to build a pattern that is anchored at the start and the end of the line. Note that you can't repeat a lookahead (that doesn't make sense since it's a zero-width assertion). You can also simply count the number of `;` occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we want:

- START OF LINE
- 0 or more non-semicolons
- **semicolon**
- 0 or more non-semicolons
- **semicolon**
- EOL

Translating to regex we get:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;$
```

For the general case with N repetitions you can use

```
^([^;]*;){N}$
```

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work. I condensed it down to: `^[^;]*;[^;]*;$`

Comment: Edited with the generalized case